# Return first 3 smallest values and their indexes from a matrix

Tags: r

I want to get the first 3 largest values in each row and coordinate for each value.

Let's say I have the following matrix:

```
           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
[1,]        4            3          6           5          2 
[2,]        5            2          1           3          6
```

Take the first row: 
I want:

```
    value    coordinate
    2           [1,5]
    3           [1,2]
    4           [1,1]
```

Currently, I am able to get the first 3 largest values in each row by something as follows:

```
# example for first row    
    a <- m[1,]
    a
    ndx <- order(a)[1:3]
    a[ndx]
```

But how to get the corresponding coordinate?

Comment: Could you please give more details here? I just start to learn R. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` to loop over the rows.  If we want the smallest values, we can simply use `order` (as in the OP's post) and select the first 3 elements.  The `order` gives the index,  and it can be used to subset the elements to create the 'value' column.  To create coordinate, we get the `order` to get the column index, replicate the rows for row index, paste them together with `sprintf`.  Use the 'value' and 'coordinate' to create a 'data.frame'.

```
value <- c(apply(m, 1, function(x) x[order(x)[1:3]]))
coordinate <- sprintf('[%d,%d]', rep(1:nrow(m), each=3),
            c(apply(m, 1, function(x) order(x)[1:3])))
df1 <- data.frame(value, coordinate, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df1
#  value coordinate
#1     2      [1,5]
#2     3      [1,2]
#3     4      [1,1]
#4     1      [2,3]
#5     2      [2,2]
#6     3      [2,4]
```

If we want the largest values, use `order(., decreasing=TRUE)` in the above code.